# Grassmann formula, dimension, subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi guys im trying to solve this exercise.
Let E, F be subspaces of R^5 of dimension 3, 4 respectively. What are the possible values for the
dimension of E ∩ F?

this is what I thought:
Since Grassmann formula is dim(E ∩ F) + dim(E + F) = dim(E) + dim(F)

How do I find it?

Comment: If $E,F\subseteq \Bbb R^5$, then what can the dimension of $E+F$ be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $U,\ W \leq V$ subspaces of a vector space V. What could the dimension of $U \cap W$ be, if $\dim{U} = 4,\ \dim{W} = 5,\ \dim{V} = 7$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4319406/let-u-w-leq-v-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-v-what-could-the-dimension-of-u)